# Misalignment problem in Opera vs Firefox/Chrome

Tags: html, css

so I'm learning CSS and i came up with this very basic page, i tried adding `<hr>` or some other seperators between the Title and the to-be `<li>` section. Chrome seems to add a rectangle to the page (sort of invisible Div) which can be seen in the screenshot(used select-all). How do i get the text/objects under title aligned properly in all browsers?

Screenshot: img194.imageshack.us/img194/9017/css00.jpg

Site/source: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23916103/layout1.html

---

SOLVED: apparently this was a bug in Opera, the rotated div on which my title text was had height set to 0 so that it has transparent background, for some unknown reason Opera replaces the 0 with some valid height.

here's a screenie ( http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/4315/divvs.jpg )
on which you can see the zero-height div that caused bug

thnx for answers.

Comment: So you just want Opera to match Firefox/Chrome?

Comment: yeah i want my seperator at the same height in all the browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox and chrome seems to be rendering it properly. Opera seems to be arguing differently with default margins... you should try something like normalize.css. And what you selected in that screenshot is just part of the body. Try inspect-element in chrome- there's no mysterious div there!

Comment: I just tried the normalize.css , doesn't seem to do anything but remove the left margin of the purple div there, i went through the normalize.css file and was unable to find anything related to my problem, also i checked if it happens because of the rotated text, apparently not, the same with invisible div(id=vertidiv) that i use for moving the seperator away from text  :/